# Mysql Arithmetic - Milliseconds to Minutes

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to return the results of a query in a more human readable format.  My query returns the average length of time for a job to complete as well as the actual length of time for a job to complete (but only when *actual > average*; in other words, it's looking for jobs that are taking longer than normal to complete and reports the avg & actual runtimes).  The database stores time values as **time in milliseconds since epoch**, so I'm trying to convert from milliseconds to minutes to make things more human readable.

However, I'm getting strange results.  Sometimes, the `actual_run_time_in_min` will be smaller than the `avg_run_time_in_min`, even though that's impossible.  It would **NOT** return the value if that were the case.  I'm sure the issue has something to do with the way I'm doing the mysql arithmetic, but I have no idea how to fix it.

*Note: I also added a multiplier (currently set to `1.4`) to increase the average run time, to make sure that a given job has definitely exceeded the expected run time.*

```
select distinct a.name, 
    TRUNCATE(((t.avgtime / 1000) % 60), 2) as avg_run_time_in_min, 
    TRUNCATE(((($CURRENT_TIME - jh.start_time) / 1000) % 60), 2) as actual_run_time_in_min
from application a 
    join job_history jh on a.id = jh.application_id
    join (
        select application_id, (avg(end_time - start_time) * $MULTIPLIER) as avgtime
        from job_history
        where status = 'SUCCESS'
        group by application_id
    ) t on a.id = t.application_id
where jh.status = 'EXECUTING' and 
   ($CURRENT_TIME - jh.start_time) > t.avgtime;
```

Here is some sample data:

**Table 1**

```
+--------+------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
| job_id |   status   |   start_time  |    end_time   | application_id |
+--------+------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
| job1   | successful | 1466064475349 | 1466064580885 | app1           |
| job2   | failed     | 1470811395368 | 1470811491037 | app2           |
| job3   | successful | 1439886075453 | 1439886081649 | app1           |
| job4   | executing  | 1470804777264 |             0 | app1           |
| job5   | successful | 1470799667312 | 1470799763746 | app3           |
+--------+------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
```

**Table 2**

```
+------+------------------+
|  id  |       name       |
+------+------------------+
| app1 | Team Green's app |
| app2 | Team Blue's app  |
| app3 | Team Red's app   |
+------+------------------+
```

Here are some actual results (not based on the sample data above):

`+---------------+---------------------+------------------------+
| name          | avg_run_time_in_min | actual_run_time_in_min |
+---------------+---------------------+------------------------+
| red-team      |               26.50 |                  48.03 |
| green-team    |               44.75 |                   5.74 |
+---------------+---------------------+------------------------+`

As you can see, the first row looks good; however, in the second row, the actual time is smaller than the average time.  Interestingly, despite the apparent issues with the arithmetic, these two jobs were the two jobs (out of many) that had exceeded their average run times.  So, the query is returning the correct results.

Comment: That's how modulo calculation works: The resulting 5.74 is equivalent to 65.74. What's the reason for using `% 60`?

Comment: You need to use `/ 60` instead of `% 60`.

Comment: Ah!  Thanks!  Yeah, for some reason that equation made sense last night!